# wordpress Gzip compession not working How can I check it in browser

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, gzip

I have Install Gzip code in my .htaccess file also enable it from options.php 
but it not showing effect.
I have check in inspect `element -> network`

but there is no any encoding type How can I enble it.
Following is my .htaccess code:

> # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML
>   and fonts   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml   AddOutputFilterByType
>   DEFLATE font/opentype   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE
>   image/svg+xml   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE
>   text/html   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain   AddOutputFilterByType
>   DEFLATE text/xml
>
> # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
>   BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html   BrowserMatch
>   ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip   BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip
>   !gzip-only-text/html   Header append Vary User-Agent

Answer (score 0):

if your website is on live server you can check if Gzip compression is on/off online using this website http://checkgzipcompression.com/

OR

To check in chrome, Open `Developer Tools` by pressing `F12`.

- Go to network tab.
- Reload the page, so that it can capture the all request.
- Find the response header `Content-Encoding: gzip`

Answer (score 0):

**What is Gzip?**

GZIP compression is bundling (zipping) pages on a web server before the page is sent to the visitor. This saves bandwidth and therefore increases the loading speed of the page significantly. The visitors' web browser then automatically unzips the pages.

**Enable Via Plugin**

https://wordpress.org/plugins/check-and-enable-gzip-compression/

**Reason for not working**

- Run on diffrent Server

  - Enable compression on NGINX webservers
  - Enable compression on Apache webservers
  - Enable compression on Litespeed webservers

**Referance link:**

https://varvy.com/pagespeed/enable-compression.html

**Edited (I am achive compression using following code)**

```
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain #content encoding Speed
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html #content encoding Speed
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml #content encoding Speed
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css #content encoding Speed
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml #content encoding Speed
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml #content encoding Speed
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml #content encoding Speed
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript #content encoding Speed
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript #content encoding Speed
        AddType x-font/otf .otf #content encoding Speed
        AddType x-font/ttf .ttf #content encoding Speed
        AddType x-font/eot .eot #content encoding Speed
        AddType x-font/woff .woff #content encoding Speed
        AddType image/x-icon .ico #content encoding Speed
        AddType image/png .png #content encoding Speed
        # content encoding Speed -- Ends here
```

Comment: I have followed all step and write down code in .htaccess file but my problem is it is not showing any effect in content-encoding 
only the response is :
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Length:132455
Content-Type:image/jpeg
Date:Mon, 05 Dec 2016 12:01:21 GMT
ETag:"20567-539b75aaa9452"
Last-Modified:Wed, 10 Aug 2016 13:09:06 GMT
Server:Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.19

Please tell how can I resolve it

Comment: Hello,@pooja,You have to give me link so i can study your website reponse header.

Comment: if you are in wordpress use gzip